# Comparator as a current detector with shunt resistor

Tags: current-measurement, voltage-measurement, comparator, orcad, over-current

I would like to design in OrCAD a comparator with a shunt resistor that will measure the voltage and when the voltage value is exceeded it will flip. I have designed the comparator but I don't know how to add the shunt resistor into the schema.

[image: Schematic of the Comparator]
[image: Simulation of the Comparator]

Comment: Do you really want to measure a voltage or the current? A shunt resistor can be used to measure a current that is flowing through a load. Unfortunately you do not seem to show a load in your circuit.

Comment: @Nedd I want to measure the voltage drop on the shunt resistor that will tell me the current. The load will be from a standard battery

Comment: The load **is** a battery, or the load is **connected** to a battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your original schematic here is an example of an over current circuit. In this example R4 (1 Ohm) is the "Shunt" resistor (a.k.a. Sense Resistor). The reference voltage is changed to 1.00 V. A 1 V sine wave is added onto a 12 V battery source to simulate the over current condition.

Without the sine wave signal the circuit would supply 12 V at 1 A to the load resistor/shunt resistor line. With the extra sine wave the current temporarily exceeds the 1 A level and the voltage on the shunt resistor will exceed 1 V. This exceeds the Vref voltage and causes the op-amp to switch to a high output.

Note that in a practical design the shunt resistor would be a much smaller value so that it would not significantly effect the load side of the circuit. With a small value shunt resistor an extra gain stage would normally be used to amplify the smaller shunt voltage.

In this arrangement the current detection is considered a "Low-Side" current measurement. There is also a "High-Side" arrangement where the shunt resistor would be placed between the battery and the load. Here is an [article from Digikey](https://www.digikey.fr/fr/articles/fundamentals-of-current-measurement-part-3-funnel-amplifiers) that includes a review of high side and low side current sensing. It also reviews a few specialized chips for that application. (If the link comes up in French click on English translation).
.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :)